# Grouping records and excluding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table name Products with columns:

```
ProductID int, 
ProductName varchar(50), 
FromDate DATETIME, 
ToDate DATETIME, 
Modified DATETIME,
ModifiedBy int
```

This table contains same `ProductNames`. `Modified` is also a `date` type column which tells about any changes made to the product on that `Modified` `date`. When any change is made to the product `ToDate` and `Modified` will be updated according to the change other wise both will be `null`

Now my requirement is :

- I want a `productname` having `ToDate` with a value
  and also with `null` in two columns
- Excluding those `Productname` with no change means having only `ToDate` and `Modified` as `NULL`
- Need Result set of Loca and Mocca

I have tried this code

```
select  *     
from     Products cpp with (nolock)  
where   (TODATE is not null and Modfied is not null)        
        or (TODATE is null and Modified is null)  
order by ProductID desc
```

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUNTu.jpg)

Comment: *also with null in two columns* and *Excluding those Productname with no change means having only ToDate and Modified as NULL* are quite contradictory. You need to provide a better explanation of what you need.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: perhaps an example or two to show what you want *and* what you are starting from.

Comment: Image added for better understandings.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit ambiguous. Try this one, even the result does not bring you the double null in the two columns but it will eliminates productname which is not modified at all:

```
select  productname, todate, modified
from    Products
group by productname, todate, modified
having sum(case when (TODATE is not null and Modfied is not null) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Data Table image added with extra note 
need only data of Loca and Mocca in Result set

Comment: the image is the result after you run the query that I gave you ?

Comment: Hey buddy it didn't yields the required Result set. This query returns only those records having both todate and modified 
i need two rows of the same product having todate and modified in one row and in other row with Nulls in todate and modified column

Answer (score 0):

```
    select  *     
    from   Products cpp with (nolock)  
    where NOT (TODATE is not null and Modfied is  null)        
    order by ProductID desc
```